# BOOL value in 64-Bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit

I have a problem with my 64-Bit IOS Simulation..

odendi is a BOOL value in my CoreDate.

This is the my entity class file.

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Fatura, Kart;

@interface Odeme : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *odendi;
```

I have a button. When user tap this button this code should run ;

```
 if (odeme.odendi == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {

        odeme.odendi = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }

    else
    {
    odeme.odendi = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    }

NSLog(@"%@",odeme.odendi);
```

It's working with 32-Bit IOS Simulation perfectly. But doesn't work in 64 Bit.When i click this button 4 times.It should **NSLog 0 1 0 1**  I tried to send

```
odeme.odendi = [NSNumber numberWithLong:1];
```

it doesn't work.

**This is the 64-Bit IOS 7.0 Iphone Simulator NSLog ;**

2014-05-04 15:15:06.971 ProjectName[5314:60b] 1

2014-05-04 15:15:07.868 ProjectName[5314:60b] 1

2014-05-04 15:15:08.662 ProjectName[5314:60b] 1

2014-05-04 15:15:08.662 ProjectName[5314:60b] 1

**This is the 32-Bit IOS 7.0 Iphone Simulation NSLog ;**

2014-05-04 15:22:01.878 ProjectName[5368:60b] 1

2014-05-04 15:22:02.770 ProjectName[5368:60b] 0

2014-05-04 15:22:04.523 ProjectName[5368:60b] 1

2014-05-04 15:22:05.399 ProjectName[5368:60b] 0

Can someone tell me what should I do ?

Thanks everyone...

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What about it is not working?  It looks like you're trying to assign an `NSNumber` object to a variable you're claiming is a BOOL.

Comment: edited my question.Please someone help

Comment: Three log statements isn't super helpful.  Can you include the entire `IBAction` method that the button calls, the variable declaration, and some sort of proof that the execution path is actually flowing through the `if` and not the `else`?  As well as any code that would be executed before the IBAction method that would initialize the variable.

Comment: You shouldn't compare NSNumbers with == like you are doing - you should use [isEqualToNumber:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought, if `odendi` is supposed to represent a BOOL, then why not use it as one?

```
if ([odeme.odendi boolValue]) {
    odeme.odendi = @NO;
} else {
    odeme.odendi = @YES;
}
```

Or even eliminate the `if-else` structure.

```
odeme.odendi = [NSNumber numberWithBool:![odeme.odendi boolValue]];
```

Or as Martin suggests some different syntax for the same statement:

```
odeme.odendi = @(![odeme.odendi boolValue]);
```

Don't miss that exclamation point.

---

Given that this seems to work on 32-bit and not on 64-bit, I suspect this might be the problem:

```
if (odeme.odendi == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
```

Which is why you should have put a log in each branch instead of just below it all.  It would let you know that your `if` is evaluating incorrectly and the problem is here, rather than inside either branch.

You could try `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`, which is different between 32-bit and 64-bit.  I have no idea if this will actually work or not.  At the end of the day though, you say `odeme.odendi` is a BOOL.  It should be used as such.  Don't compare it to a number.  Don't even compare it to an `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES]` or `@YES`.  Just grab the BOOL value.  It will evaluate to YES or NO and the correct branch should be chosen.

Comment: Or with a "boxed expression": `odeme.odendi = @(![odeme.odendi boolValue]);`

Comment: Thank you for answers. They are very helpful and i solved my problem thanks to you guys.

Comment: @leonthegosu: If this answer helped to solve your problem then you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: yea i forgot the accept answers sorry for that. Thank you again.